# Multiplication Grid function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've made a small function to output a [multiplication grid](http://www.bbc.co.uk/staticarchive/cd9eacd017f9e693f21a9752cc73b9dc3af99430.gif) (those things from primary school! :P) to an inputted number.

```
def make_grid(max):
    max += 1  # so the for loops go up to the desired number, inclusive
    print('X\t' + '\t'.join([str(_) for _ in range(max)]) + '\n')  # print all the numbers hoizontally
    for i in range(max):
        print(i, end="\t")  # print the vertical column of base numbers
        for x in range(max):
            print(str(i*x), end="\t")  # multiply the two numbers
        print('\n')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        max = int(input("Max Number? "))
        make_grid(max)
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a number!")
```

Choosing a max number of 5 (`make_grid(5)`) would output:

> ```
> X 0   1   2   3   4   5
>
> 0 0   0   0   0   0   0   
>
> 1 0   1   2   3   4   5   
>
> 2 0   2   4   6   8   10  
>
> 3 0   3   6   9   12  15  
>
> 4 0   4   8   12  16  20  
>
> 5 0   5   10  15  20  25
> ```

I'm looking for any improvements I could make, especially the `\t`'s - as I use them to line up the numbers, but the gap gets pretty big, unnecessarily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`make_grid()` isn't quite the right name for this function, as it is *printing* a grid rather than returning a grid.  I think you would be better off returning a long string to be printed.

In your list comprehension, `_` is a bad choice for the iteration variable name, since `_` indicates a throwaway value, by convention.  If you then call `str(_)`, you should pick a different name.

Besides the excessively wide spacing as you have observed, using tabs is problematic because the output would be better with the entries right-aligned.  You also have a superfluous tab at the end of each line (except the header row).

#### Suggested solution

Use [`'{0:>{width}}'.format(…)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) to print the entries right-aligned with a fixed width.

```
def multiplication_grid(max):
    max += 1    # Inclusive upper bound for ranges
    grid = [['X'] + [j for j in range(max)]] + \
             [[i] + [i * j for j in range(max)] for i in range(max)]

    # Use fixed-width right alignment for every entry in the 2D grid
    width = 2 + len(str(max * max))
    fmt = lambda n: '{0:>{width}}'.format(n, width=width)
    return '\n\n'.join(''.join(fmt(entry) for entry in row) for row in grid)
```

`[['X'] + [j for j in range(max)]]` creates the header row.

`[[i] + [i * j for j in range(max)] for i in range(max)]` is a nested list comprehension to create the rest of the rows, where `i` is the row number and `j` is the column number.

[`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda) is a way to define very simple functions that do nothing more than returning an expression.  The lambda could also have been written as:

```
    def fmt(n):
        return '{0:>{width}}'.format(n, width=width)
```

The last line applies `fmt()` to every entry in the two-dimensional grid and joins everything into a single string.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is ok, but `make_grid` does not only make a grid, it also prints it nicely.

Remember, one function, one task.

I would use two functions:

```
def make_grid(limit):
    return [[i * j for i in range(limit)] for j in range(limit)]
```

`make_grid` just builds a grid as a list of lists of numbers, the way the computer likes it. We may use this output as the input to a variety of other functions.

```
def print_numeric_grid(grid, spacing):
    for line in grid:
        print(''.join(' ' * (spacing - len(str(i))) + str(i) for i in line))
```

`print_numeric_grid` has an easy job, the grid already exists so printing it is a piece of cake. Most of the logic is to indent it all nicely, without that the code would be even simpler.

Comment: Thanks +1 :) How does the indenting logic work? And what is the `spacing` parameter?

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Spacing indicates the number of spaces between numbers. Indenting logic is just a subtraction